# India flight security checks

Tags: india, security, check-in

While booking a ticket for someone, I used her first name and husband's initials (Kalyani S) instead of her full name (Kalyani Chaudhary). Her Aadhar card and other documents provide her full name.

What can I do to ensure she has hassle free entry through security and the rest of her travel? Will supporting documents help?